# Mysql + Classic asp having count alternative

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have basket table like this:

```
          BasketTable
          BasketID         -   ProductID      - Total
              1            |        1         |   1
              2            |        2         |   1
              3            |        3         |   1
              4            |        4         |   2
```

I use this query `(Note : ProductID some times 1,2,3 or 1,2)`

```
select * from BasketTable
where ProductID in (1,2,3,4) and Total > 0
Having Count(*) = 4
```

Query Result:

```
            BasketTable
            BasketID      -  ProductID  
                1         |      1
```

I need this

```
           BasketTable
          BasketID         -   ProductID       
              1            |        1          
              2            |        2          
              3            |        3          
              4            |        4
```

Comment: What is your expected output in plain english? Btw, I guess a BasketId can have many ProductId, right?

Comment: why a count(*)=4 and why you need to return all rows?

Comment: thanks for edit mosty, sorry for my bad english, why i need Count(*) = 4 because i need BasketIDs because i try make this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051760/mysql-classic-asp-full-matched-query-with-in

Comment: "HAVING" has no meaning without a "GROUP BY" clause. What are you trying to count?

Comment: thanks, you know how can i select same time four id select in table without "IN" ?